# Adding KMM support on Existing Android project makes Room go berzerk

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a KMM shared module in my existing Android project, I added a simple class, made a graphql query and that's about it. Now, if I have an older version of the app installed on my device, and then update to this newer one which has KMM support ... i get this

`Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.`

I checked the changes, I never touched any of the entities nor the database. Why would the existing database go berzerk for no apparent reason ?!

Dependencies I used, in case it matters in any way:

```
api("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.7.4")

api("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:$reaktiveVersion")
api("com.badoo.reaktive:coroutines-interop:$reaktiveVersion")

implementation("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-no-arg:$multiplatformSettings")
```

Comment: Well, I can't imagine how those libraries would do anything to your DB. I would start by getting the source for the old version and pushing that build to an emulator, then locally try to update that app to the KMM version and see if Room reports the same issue locally. If so, I'd copy the db from the emulator to your dev drive, then increase the db version number and push to the emulator, and get another copy of the db file. You can then manually compare them to see what the changes are.

Comment: Already tried it locally, and I can replicate it. Issue is not yet in production, thankfully! That copy the db idea is not bad though ...

Comment: Well, if you can figure out what Room wants to change, that'll help backtrack to why it thinks it needs to change.

Comment: Ok, so here's the thing, I compared and initially it was `created_at TEXT` and now it's been somehow forced to `created_at TET NOT NULL` ... Besides integrating KMM i also updated gradle stuff and google services and other dependencies and things. I checked and I never touched the created_at field in the code. I could simply create a migration and update it to what it actually requires, but ... i'd still like to figure out the root cause of this...

Comment: It's defined like this ... not even a @nonNull annotation or anything. Hmm ...
@ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private var createdAt: String = ""